# How to display the property of an image displayed on the asp page by selecting relevant radio button

Tags: c#, .net, ascx

Actually I'm working on an `ascx` file which displays images in a specified folder.

The task is to place a radio button for each image, and when a radio-button is selected, the details (like the image's name) of the appropriate image should be shown in a pop-up box.

Please, help me finish the task!

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlAssignftp" Visible="false" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Vertical"
    HorizontalAlign="left" CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1" Width="100%">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <ul class="gallery clearfix slideshow">
            <li>
                <a href='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Image Path") %>' rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]">                
                <asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Image Path") %>' ID="imgftp"
                    runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px" Visible="true" />
                 </a>
            </li>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn_ftpimg" runat="server" Text="Select" GroupName="rbtn_ftpimg_grp" Checked="false" TextAlign="Right" OnCheckedChanged="rbtn_ftpimg_Changed" AutoPostBack="true"  />
        </ul>
        <%--</a>--%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what properties you are looking for exactly you could do something like this:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(<path to image on server>);
//return data to web: img.Width, img.Height etc.
```

Additionally I *think* you can do something like this:

```
PropertyItem[] itms = img.PropertyItems;
foreach(PropertyItem item in itms)
{
      //iterate through items and do work
}
```

Does that help?

--- Edit ---

The above code should give you the details you are looking for but as far as how you go about displaying them is entirely up to you.  What I would *probably* do would be something similar to the following:

```
 <script language="javascript">
 function GetImageDetails(id)
 {
    $.ajax({
    url: '/Images/GetImageDetails',
    type: "POST",
    data: { imageId: id },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
            var content;
            content = data[0].Width;
            content += "<br>";
            content += data[0].Height;
            content += "<br>";
            //etc
            alert(content);
    }
   });
 }
 </script>
 <input type=radio onClick="GetImageDetails(1);">
```

Then on the server side you might have a webservice that looks like this:

```
 public JsonResult GetImageDetails(int ID)
 {
     var img = Image.FromFile(<path to image on server>);
     return Json(new { width = img.Width, height = img.Height });
 }
```

You could modify this any number of ways to suit your needs.  For example you will notice that I pass an id parameter into the Web Service method (I don't do anything with it in the example however) which I would use to pull the physical location of the image out of the database.  Alternatively you could just pass in the path to the image to avoid the round trip to the database server.  Again how you go about doing this is really up to you.

One final point the above web service method is akin to what you would find in an MVC 3/4 environment.  If you are not running MVC you could do something like this instead:

```
 public string GetImageDetails(int ID)
 {
     var img = Image.FromFile(<path to image on server>);
     var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     return serializer.Serialize(new { width = img.Width, height = img.Height });
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sry not quite, actually it is a live site which already shows images which are loaded using FTP, and the ascx shows the img in a datalist, my wrk is to place radio button for each image(as no of imgs and img loc may vary), and wen the rB is selected the details for the appropriate img shud be shown in a alert box, do u have any idea?